# When exactly the built-in postfix increment operator returns the result?

Tags: c++, operators, language-lawyer

I know two things about the built-in postfix increment operator:

1. Firstly the result value is evaluated (i.e. prvalue copy of the operand is created).
2. Only after that the side effect (increment) is applied to the original object.

So when exactly this operator **returns** the result? I see three options here:

**a)** immediately after its evaluation
(i.e. after 1. In this case "returning the result" is equivalent to "evaluate the result")
**b)** in some moment between 1. and 2.
**c)** after completion of the side effect (after 2.)?

Which option is technically correct?

**Edit**: Maybe this question refers to more general question:
"returning the result of operator/expression" is the same thing as "evaluating the result of operator/expression" or not?

**P.S.** I know this is a stupid question but I didn't find answer to it. It bothers me because there are other operators (and expressions) with side effects which are completed after evaluating result.

Comment: How could it be anything but (c)?  Also, incrementing the variable is not a side effect..

Comment: The only thing it returns is the value of the object it was applied to. So, none of the above.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec#Built-in_postfix_operators) claims that increment is a side effect

Comment: @Nathan That would depend on the compiler doing a lot of analysis on what foo() does.

Comment: The question as stated doesn't really make sense. Evaluations are not generally arranged in a sequential timeline, so if's meaningless to talk about "when". The standard says: "**[expr.post.incr]/1** The value computation of the `++` expression is sequenced before the modification of the operand object." That's the only guarantee. In particular, the side effect is generally unsequenced with respect to other subexpressions of the full expression.

Comment: @Rodv It says "Because of the side-effects involved [for all such operators]", but not what they are. To me at least, incrementing a variable via ++ is not a side effect.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Incrementing a variable is in fact a side effect, by definition. "**[intro.execution]/12** Accessing an object designated by a `volatile` glvalue (3.10), modifying an object, calling a library I/O function, or calling a function that does any of those operations are all *side effects*, which are changes in the state of the execution environment."

Comment: @NeilButterworth, it says: "**As a side-effect**, for non-boolean operands, the expression x++ modifies the value of its operand as if by evaluating x += 1, and the expression x-- modifies the value of its operand as if by evaluating x -= 1." I think it's clear that they think that increment is a side effect

Comment: @Igor Thank you. It;s kind of hard to think of `x = 1` being a side effect  in a procedural language though.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, so all three options (a, b, c) are possible, yes?

Comment: I'm not even sure what it means to "return the result" as an action separate from "evaluate the value". Expressions have values, and some also produce side effects. They don't actively "return" anything. Like I said, I believe the question as stated is meaningless, and therefore impossible to answer.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, That's why I asked this question! I wanted to know: "returning the result of operator/expression" is the same thing as "evaluating the result of operator/expression" or not.

Comment: The C++ standard never talks about "returning the result of an expression". If you want to make up a new term, then of course you can assign any meaning you want to it. In particular, you can declare that, from here on out, whenever you say "the result of an expression is returned" you mean "an expression is evaluated" (the latter as defined by the standard). In which case, I suppose, **(a)** would be true, by definition. It's not clear to me though how this would help you solve any problem or advance your understanding of any matter; it's counting angels on the head of a pin, at this point.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, ok. It's clear now about expressions. But in the Standard I often see phrases "operator returns the result" and "operator evalutes the result" in the context of expression. These two phrases mean the same thing or not?

Comment: @Igor Mind to write an answer based on these facts?

Comment: Ah, yes, I see a few spots like this. E.g. "**[expr.log.or]/1** The `||` operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both contextually converted to bool (Clause 4). It returns `true` if either of its operands is `true`, and `false` otherwise." That's just a bit of sloppy writing, really; possibly an editorial oversight. Compare with how `&&` is described, right above it: "**[expr.log.and]/1** The `&&` operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both contextually converted to type bool (Clause 4).
The result is `true` if both operands are `true` and `false` otherwise."