# How can a built-in operator (except new, delete and function call) return?

Tags: c++, operators, language-lawyer

I have found next built-in operators which can **return** in Clause 5:
new, delete, function call, logical OR, all assignments operators.

It's all clear about the first three operators:

- new operator usually calls allocation function which returns the
  result.
- delete operator usually calls deallocation function which
  returns the result.
- The result of a function call is usually the
  result of the operand of the evaluated return statement in the called
  function.

Other built-in operators didn't call functions. **So how they can return something?**
We can say only that such operators evaluate the result value or produce side effects like any other expressions.
Are there two inaccuracies in the Standard about built-in logical AND and built-in assignment operators?

Let's look at logical OR (§5.15/1):

> The || operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both
>   contextually converted to bool (Clause 4). It **returns** true if either
>   of its operands is true, and false otherwise.

Compare with the technically correct definition of logical AND (§5.14/1):

> The && operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both
>   contextually converted to bool (Clause 4). **The result is** true if both
>   operands are true and false otherwise.

Why they used "returns" in case of || operator and "the result is" in case of logical AND?

Next look at the built-in assignment operators (§5.18/1).

> All require a modifiable lvalue as their left operand and **return** an
>   lvalue referring to the left operand.

Again we see "return" instead of "the result is".

**P.S.** I didn't find any phrases like "expression returns" in the Standard so it seems that such phrases are technically incorrect. Using them may [cause strange questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42306545/when-exactly-the-built-in-postfix-increment-operator-returns-the-result)

Comment: I see nothing outrageous in the terminology above. You just have to get accustomed to the fact that operators (infix postfix or whatever) are just a syntax to call functions with strange names (only with short-circuit ones being a bit magical). Once you mentally replace `a || b` with `operator||(a,b)` the fact that it "returns" a result doesn't feel so strange.

Comment: Built-in operators are not functions.

Comment: It's irrelevant. It's as if they were, and the distinction is just stupid technicality even in the mind of who wrote the standard, as testified by the terminology above.

Comment: An operator or a function would return its result, so its not that important which way you specify it.

Comment: @MatteoItalia you mean there is absolutely no differrence between concepts "returning the result" and "evaluating the result value" for operators?

Comment: Not that I know of, at least for built in types (which are the only ones that are interesting for the rules of built in operators). But C++ being C++ (needlessly complicated for no good reason), I won't be completely surprised if someone comes up with some obscure corner case where there's some technical difference that no compiler actually cares about.

Comment: ok. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: The same (lack of) distinction would apply to an inlined function.

Answer (score 1):

From the discussion above (thanks to *Matteo Italia*) we can conclude that there is absolutely NO difference between concepts "return the result" and "yield/evaluate the result value" for built-in operators (at least for built-in types which are the only ones that are interesting for the rules of built in operators).